# KeyCloak on Kubernetes not connecting with external MySQL

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am trying to run KeyCloak on kubernetes and connect to external MySQL database. I deployed using the `deployment.yaml` and `service.yaml` as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: {{K8S_NAMESPACE}}
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: keycloak
      annotations:
        sla: high
        tier: application
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: harbor-bot
      serviceAccount: tenant-pod-root
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:14.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 750m
            memory: 768Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 750m
            memory: 768Mi
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_USER}}
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}}
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_DB_VENDOR}}
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}}
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE}}
        - name: DB_USER
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}}
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: {{KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}}
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: JDBC_PARAMS
          value: "useSSL=false"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
----------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: keycloak
  namespace: {{K8S_NAMESPACE}}
  name: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp-upstream
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: keycloak
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

When I try to run this yaml in kubernetes, I get the following error:

```
12:41:55,174 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) WFLYCTL0403: Unexpected failure during execution of the following operation(s): [{
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [("subsystem" => "naming")]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "naming"),
        ("service" => "remote-naming")
    ]
}]: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0195: Interrupted awaiting transaction commit or rollback
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:458)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelController$OperationTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ModelController.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeDoneStage(AbstractOperationContext.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:805)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:384)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

12:41:55,173 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0403: Unexpected failure during execution of the following operation(s): [{
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [("subsystem" => "jgroups")],
    "default-channel" => "ee"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("channel" => "ee")
    ],
    "stack" => "udp",
    "cluster" => "ejb"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("transport" => "UDP")
    ],
    "socket-binding" => "jgroups-udp"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "PING")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "MERGE3")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "FD_SOCK")
    ],
    "socket-binding" => "jgroups-udp-fd"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "FD_ALL")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "VERIFY_SUSPECT")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.NAKACK2")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "UNICAST3")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.STABLE")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.GMS")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "UFC")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "MFC")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "udp"),
        ("protocol" => "FRAG3")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("transport" => "TCP")
    ],
    "socket-binding" => "jgroups-tcp"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "MPING")
    ],
    "socket-binding" => "jgroups-mping"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "MERGE3")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "FD_SOCK")
    ],
    "socket-binding" => "jgroups-tcp-fd"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "FD_ALL")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "VERIFY_SUSPECT")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.NAKACK2")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "UNICAST3")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.STABLE")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "pbcast.GMS")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "MFC")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
        ("stack" => "tcp"),
        ("protocol" => "FRAG3")
    ]
}]: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0195: Interrupted awaiting transaction commit or rollback
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:458)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelController$OperationTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ModelController.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeDoneStage(AbstractOperationContext.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:805)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:384)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

12:41:55,173 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) WFLYCTL0403: Unexpected failure during execution of the following operation(s): [{
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [("subsystem" => "elytron")],
    "final-providers" => "combined-providers",
    "disallowed-providers" => ["OracleUcrypto"]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("aggregate-providers" => "combined-providers")
    ],
    "providers" => [
        "elytron",
        "openssl"
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("provider-loader" => "elytron")
    ],
    "module" => "org.wildfly.security.elytron"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("provider-loader" => "openssl")
    ],
    "module" => "org.wildfly.openssl"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("file-audit-log" => "local-audit")
    ],
    "path" => "audit.log",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.log.dir",
    "format" => "JSON"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("security-domain" => "ApplicationDomain")
    ],
    "default-realm" => "ApplicationRealm",
    "permission-mapper" => "default-permission-mapper",
    "realms" => [
        {
            "realm" => "ApplicationRealm",
            "role-decoder" => "groups-to-roles"
        },
        {"realm" => "local"}
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("security-domain" => "ManagementDomain")
    ],
    "default-realm" => "ManagementRealm",
    "permission-mapper" => "default-permission-mapper",
    "realms" => [
        {
            "realm" => "ManagementRealm",
            "role-decoder" => "groups-to-roles"
        },
        {
            "realm" => "local",
            "role-mapper" => "super-user-mapper"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("identity-realm" => "local")
    ],
    "identity" => "$local"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("properties-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
    ],
    "users-properties" => {
        "path" => "application-users.properties",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir",
        "digest-realm-name" => "ApplicationRealm"
    },
    "groups-properties" => {
        "path" => "application-roles.properties",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
    }
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("properties-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
    ],
    "users-properties" => {
        "path" => "mgmt-users.properties",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir",
        "digest-realm-name" => "ManagementRealm"
    },
    "groups-properties" => {
        "path" => "mgmt-groups.properties",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
    }
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("simple-permission-mapper" => "default-permission-mapper")
    ],
    "mapping-mode" => "first",
    "permission-mappings" => [
        {
            "principals" => ["anonymous"],
            "permission-sets" => [{"permission-set" => "default-permissions"}]
        },
        {
            "match-all" => true,
            "permission-sets" => [
                {"permission-set" => "login-permission"},
                {"permission-set" => "default-permissions"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("constant-realm-mapper" => "local")
    ],
    "realm-name" => "local"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("simple-role-decoder" => "groups-to-roles")
    ],
    "attribute" => "groups"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("constant-role-mapper" => "super-user-mapper")
    ],
    "roles" => ["SuperUser"]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("permission-set" => "login-permission")
    ],
    "permissions" => [{"class-name" => "org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"}]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("permission-set" => "default-permissions")
    ],
    "permissions" => [
        {
            "class-name" => "org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission",
            "module" => "org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet",
            "target-name" => "*"
        },
        {
            "class-name" => "org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission",
            "module" => "org.wildfly.transaction.client"
        },
        {
            "class-name" => "org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission",
            "module" => "org.jboss.ejb-client"
        },
        {
            "class-name" => "org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission",
            "module" => "org.jboss.ejb-client"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("http-authentication-factory" => "management-http-authentication")
    ],
    "security-domain" => "ManagementDomain",
    "http-server-mechanism-factory" => "global",
    "mechanism-configurations" => [{
        "mechanism-name" => "DIGEST",
        "mechanism-realm-configurations" => [{"realm-name" => "ManagementRealm"}]
    }]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("provider-http-server-mechanism-factory" => "global")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("sasl-authentication-factory" => "application-sasl-authentication")
    ],
    "sasl-server-factory" => "configured",
    "security-domain" => "ApplicationDomain",
    "mechanism-configurations" => [
        {
            "mechanism-name" => "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER",
            "realm-mapper" => "local"
        },
        {
            "mechanism-name" => "DIGEST-MD5",
            "mechanism-realm-configurations" => [{"realm-name" => "ApplicationRealm"}]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("sasl-authentication-factory" => "management-sasl-authentication")
    ],
    "sasl-server-factory" => "configured",
    "security-domain" => "ManagementDomain",
    "mechanism-configurations" => [
        {
            "mechanism-name" => "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER",
            "realm-mapper" => "local"
        },
        {
            "mechanism-name" => "DIGEST-MD5",
            "mechanism-realm-configurations" => [{"realm-name" => "ManagementRealm"}]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("configurable-sasl-server-factory" => "configured")
    ],
    "sasl-server-factory" => "elytron",
    "properties" => {"wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" => "$local"}
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory" => "elytron")
    ],
    "sasl-server-factory" => "global",
    "filters" => [{"provider-name" => "WildFlyElytron"}]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("provider-sasl-server-factory" => "global")
    ]
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("key-store" => "applicationKS")
    ],
    "credential-reference" => {"clear-text" => "password"},
    "type" => "JKS",
    "path" => "application.keystore",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("key-manager" => "applicationKM")
    ],
    "key-store" => "applicationKS",
    "generate-self-signed-certificate-host" => "localhost",
    "credential-reference" => {"clear-text" => "password"}
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
        ("server-ssl-context" => "applicationSSC")
    ],
    "key-manager" => "applicationKM"
}]: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0195: Interrupted awaiting transaction commit or rollback
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:458)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelController$OperationTransactionControl.operationPrepared(ModelController.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeDoneStage(AbstractOperationContext.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:805)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:384)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

The user I have given to keycloak is already created as well as the database as in [here](https://medium.com/@pratik.dandavate/setting-up-keycloak-standalone-with-mysql-database-7ebb614cc229).

I am not sure why there is an error like - `java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0195: Interrupted awaiting transaction commit or rollback`

This is really confusing. The same keycloak runs without MySQL totally fine.

Comment: Hi @mifol68042, Have you found any solution to this? I am also facing same issue, Can you please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: i had no luck with this. i set it up using docker compose in local since it was only for dev purpose

Comment: I have found the solution, there was an issue with mysql driver class and module mapping.

Comment: can you share the solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with defining module as :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

And based on this module use driver in standalone.xml as:

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
       <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

This is what helped me to get ride of this issue.